# Does a bank have to tell me if a check made out to me was cashed there?

Tags: united-states, fraud, deposits, paycheck, kentucky

I moved out of a place and I was supposed to receive my last pay check there. I think my housemate deposited it in his account. I know banks are not supposed to, but it's in a small town so people trust people more.

Also, my housemate and I worked at the same place. He and the boss are best friends. It's a Minit Mart gas station where we worked, and the boss will not tell me my Paycor access code for payroll or email it to me. Human Resources won't call back but the boss said the check should have already arrived.

So I called his bank to see if my check was cashed there. The man on the phone took all my information and put me on hold, then he came back and said, "I can't tell you that information." I asked, "What if I come in, bring all my identification?" He still said, "No".

Do I have the right to know if my check was deposited in my housemate's account without my permission? My name was never with his bank account and I don't have a bank account of my own.

Answer (score 44):

**You are going about this wrong.**

To start with your actual question, no your friend's bank has no duty or right to tell you about anything that your friend did as part of their banking.

What you need to do is this.

1. Go to your employer and tell them you did not receive your paycheque. If they say it was delivered to your address get them to put that in writing and ask if they have proof, such as registered delivery. If they are not sure, wait until enough time has passed that it definitely should have arrived, and then tell them it is missing and ask them to make another one. (This should not be a problem for them as they can stop the old one if it hasn't been cashed).
2. If they are completely sure it was delivered,  or has been cashed, tell them you think the cheque was stolen. Ask if the cheque was cashed and if they can find who cashed it. They should be able to find out from their bank who cashed it. Tell them you will be contacting the police to try to find it.
3. Go to your housemates and tell them that the cheque was definitely delivered to their address. Ask them if they are sure it was not delivered. Tell them you will be contacting the police to track the cheque down.
4. Go to your bank and tell them you suspect a cheque made out to you was stolen. They may be able to help.
5. Go to the police. Tell them everything you know. They have the power to get the information you want from the banks.
6. You may also be able to pursue a claim for unpaid wages,  but you would need to get a lawyer to advise you in that.

It's best not to accuse people unless you have evidence. But if the cheque was stolen by someone you know, mentioning the police may cause them to suddenly find the cheque or give you another one.

Comment: It was sent to his house and  my old employer and my old friend are good friends so my boss won't email me my payroll access code and I have tried email payroll and I was not really asking anything about his bank history  but if I check in my name was cashed illeagly why don't they have to tell me it was cashed it I mean  the bank should not have did it and I'm about 110% sure he did do it but I'm trying to get evidence so I can do something so my question still not answered

Comment: @ElijahRatliff You're trying to gather evidence that your old friend cashed your check illegally.  Stop doing that.  Start gathering evidence that *you didn't get your paycheck* - as DJ suggests - and then take *that evidence* to the police.  You don't need to solve the case by yourself, you just need enough solid evidence that *something is wrong* to get an official investigation started.

Comment: Well first off police can't do nothing it's a civil matter so it would be the local county attorney and tried that no call back 2 weeks I don't have my paycheck bank or payroll info like I said and I said  if there was a check deposit and my bad I should have said cashed also but your saying even if I don't want nothing to  know but a statement from the bank with a copy of the check saying it was cash there to go to the court and file small claim suit on the bank or have the bank investigat it and refund  my money because it is against there policy to deposit a check if it's not in the accou

Comment: The account owner name so that's the bank fault and my old supervisor has the power to send me a access code for paycor so I can see payroll he will not he friends with my old friend he said I should already have a email I don't he won't send another email and I call mint mart he payroll  and I leave a message everyday at e.g. group  headcorder in Ohio so I tried all that

Comment: If a cheque made out to you was cashed without your permission that's criminal. If a letter addressed to you was opened that's criminal. The police are definitely the place to go.

Comment: Ok well I'm I agree but I have done that  but I'm trying to get something done I mean they could have already it been two weeks and not even a call and there looking into in. It is against the banks policy to cash or deposit a check if you don't have or a co owner of a account there and so I was wondering all it was if the bank was legally able to say no I'm not giving you no if to take to the police or county attorney to get something file buy a judge to get my money or pretty sure if a teller deposit my check against bank policy the would  have to refund my money but was just wonder for sho

Comment: I mean everyone thanks for the help but all you all what I'm I am asking  I don't want nobody bank information I just wanted what legal rights I had and against that bank because there policy to even do that and one of there workers did I know but when I go in person my legal rights because when you try to do something the right way to go to a company  and than the law and nothing and I know what happen and told the,

Comment: @ElijahRatliff You ask for advice, you're given **good** advice, and you  ignore it.  That's Not Smart.

Comment: @ElijahRatliff The problem is that you think you're asking the bank for information about *yourself*, and you aren't.  Your employer's bank knows if the check was cashed.  *Your* bank doesn't.  You seem to think they can just tell you about activity in your roommate's account, and they absolutely and definitely cannot do that.  Your roommate's account has nothing to do with you.  Contact your state's Attorney General and request to talk to the wage theft unit.  (Not because you think your roommate stole your wages, but because your *employer* has stolen them and is ignoring your calls.)

Comment: check fraud certainly isn't a civil matter, it's a criminal offense... and the bank should have never ever cashed the check without having been shown valid ID (or knowing the person by the name; whatever it's KYC) - so whatever bank which cashed it out did not act according to the processing standards for checks. the postman, neighbors and by-passers might be other possible suspects. I'd also suggest to first report the loss to the employer, wait another week and then open an investigation into it - because police will be allowed to gather the evidence about the suspect, which you never will.

Comment: well, option number two might be: the check was never sent. best is to ask by email and not on the phone - so you have at least some information with a timestamp and sender address, which quite unlikely might be forged, eg. when it's GMail or alike service (it's rather valid evidence, when not hosting the server oneself ...it's more alike a third party witness).

Comment: @ElijahRatliff civil matters **do not** go to the local county attorney. They go to **your** attorney.  Paycheck matters are neither one; they go to the Labor Cabinet. I know you are very, very sure you are right, but might I gently point out, this has not passed the "reality" test. If you were right, your paycheck would be in your hands.

Answer (score 15):

No, they do not. However that is the wrong side of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You *really* want your paycheck! As such I will answer that.  This is called a "[frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t/263672#263672)" and is legit here.

*Also keep in mind they have 14 days to prepare your last check, plus mailing time.  It simply may not have arrived yet.*

### You are overthinking this. *And missing the point.*

The relevant thing is you did not get your paycheck.  Full STOP.

Yes, I know you have a brain full of very complex stories that you want to spew in stream-of-consciousness fashion, as we've seen in OP and two answers so far. *Stop doing that Right Now because **you have no idea what actually happened**. All your guesswork is unconstructive*.  In fact if I was your roommate and you went around town saying that about me, I'd take your next hundred paychecks because *that is slander*.

You don't know.  It might have been destroyed in a mail-bin fire.  It might have fallen out of the postal carrier's bag. It might be delayed in the mail. The roommate might be holding it for you and forgot.

Keep in mind too. Everyone you need to help you *is lazy and would love to find a reason to NOT help you.*

So you go to your employer (walk right into their shop!!!) and you say

> I never got my last paycheck.  (fullstop)

That is a serious problem and there are big consequences for cheating an employee out of their last check.  They don't want to deal with a Labor Commission investigation after all.  Therefore, they will want to help you.

Now consider what happens if you start running your mouth with your big fat story about your suspicions about your roommate. Nobody wants to deal with an opinionated idiot, so they'll say "sounds like you DO know where your paycheck went, so you don't need us.  Best of luck dealing with him, **Buh-*bye***."

So keep your trap shut.

Of course they will say "It was delivered to so-and-so address." And you say

> I don't live there anymore.

Did you notice the part where you stop talking? Good.

They might also ask "Did you check with anyone there to see if they received it?"

> I did. They assure me they did not receive it.

AND SHUT UP.   Yes, I know you are exploding with the urge to tell them your whole conspiracy theory about your roommate cashing it.  Shut up shut up shut up.  You don't *know* and guesswork only hurts.

Now who knows what's going to happen?  They will investigate of course, but they will want to see if you in fact did cash it.   It should be apparent in their invesigation that you did *not*, so they should reissue it without further ado.  If this check was stolen by someone, they will chargeback the account it was deposited into, which would suck for that person.  **This is a big bag of Not Your Problem**.  The system will deal with it.  You don't have to be Nancy Drew here.

### My employer refused to deal with me / talk to me

Then you go straight to your state's Labor Commission and file a complaint.  This is pretty easy, and the employer will really, really, really hate it.

### My employer worked with me, but swears I cashed the check

Then straight to the police and report check fraud. They can dig into which account it was deposited into and who owns that account, or if it was cashed at a pink neon check cashing place, the cops can force them to pull their CCTV tapes and see who stood there and cashed it.  All of this is also **a big bag of Not Your Problem.

Don't Nancy Drew this stuff, becuse in the real world, people who play Veronica Mars/amiss Marple/Agatha Raisin *get treated as suspects because they know too much*.

At some point in the investigation, it's *possible* a cop will ask you "Do you have any suspicions about what happened?"

> Now.  Finally! Now!  You get to tell your crazy story.

But the next thing he'll say is "Do you have any reason to believe this?"

Answer (score 1):

Wage theft is a serious matter. If your former housemate's friendship with your former boss resulted in your wages for your final paycheck being diverted (i.e. deposited) to your friend's bank account, it would be **criminal** activity by your former employer, Minit Mart, by your former boss if he facilitated it, and by your friend for taking part.

All banks are subject to KYC ("Know Your Customer") requirements. Any bank that accepted a check for deposit that was payable to you and only you, but was not endorsed by you, and for which your name was not on the depositor account, could be subject to criminal charges at a federal level. There is an entire division that concerns itself with such matters, FinCEN aka Financial Crimes Enforcement Network. FinCEN has authority whether you live in a small community with high levels of personal trust or not.

Regarding Paycor, you may wish to do the [following](https://www.paycor.com/contact):

> Employees of a Paycor client company can contact their company's HR
>   department for questions about payroll, time cards & other HR matters.
>   For general information about Paycor, please call 800.381.0053 or [contact us online](https://www.paycor.com/contact/general).

Comment: Can't get to I'm still waiting for hr been bout a mount still call they put a report  in for me and only hr administers can give me a access code paycor iv called when you do it say get ahold of minsrater so I did just to a tech a paycor and I thought they was gonna help she told me let me put you on hold then it went to a computer  talking saying get ahold of my employer and hung up they can't help me get it it's like adp if you old employee lose password can't get ahold o hr you can't get it from them

Comment: And adp has access code when u start to don't have it can't register but see I had a employer that they went threw them when I got on the payroll I got a access code imeditly  I can get on adp no prob

Answer (score 1):

There is no bank in the United States that could answer your question even if they wanted to.  Banks maintain a photographic copy of all items in the order they were processed by the bank’s proof department, for those that use them, and in the order of teller presentation if they do not use a proof operation.  Items are assigned numbers, starting with 1 and continuing until they run out of numbers and start over.   There is no way to look up any one item unless you first get a copy of the original item, which you do not have.

A bank can find a check in one of two ways.  The first is to know the specific transaction as it processed through a specific account.  There is a tracking number that allows the recall of the item’s image.  The other way is to present a copy of the original item from the issuer’s bank.  It allows the tracking of the item by the numbers stamped on it.  In the worst case, it can be traced via database searches for items with the same routing and transit number, account number, and dollar amount.

No bank could ever do what you ask.  A small bank would process 250-350 thousand items per day.  Which one?  For a large bank, it is in the hundreds of millions.

It is also irrelevant to your problem.  The issue is between you and your employer.  Even if your roommate committed fraud, they are not part of the resolution of this as far as you are concerned.

Go to your employer.  There are many potential explanations.  You have no legal capacity to run this down yourself.  For that matter, neither do the police without a warrant.  Your employer is the only answer here.

If they say it was cashed, then you will need to fill out an affidavit of forgery and get the check reissued, and you could then involve the police.  If it was not cashed, then they will likely require you to wait.  It could be due to postal delays or have been lost in the mail.  They will also have an internal processing time for replacement checks.

The only time you would involve an attorney would be in the case where it was not cashed, and they would not reissue.  In that case, you are probably going to be out of luck as the amount is small, and the attorney probably wouldn’t bother taking your case.  You could involve the state’s Attorney General or the state’s wage and hour commission.  If they are not paying though, then they probably lack the funds and so you would be trying to get blood out of a rock.