# Check Cashed By someone else

Tags: united-states, check, fraud, new-york

I am facing one weird situation.

I am about receive check for my kid’s summer camp refund. Summer camp agency issued a check and it was never delivered to me. When I contact them they said its already paid to me, also the same information showing in their system.

Tragedy is I never received a check.

Please guide me what to do in this situation.

I am in Queens NY.

Comment: I am in Queens-NY

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://money.stackexchange.com/a/109835/36669

Comment: Thanks...in my case someone en-cashed my check that what being told to me by the summer camp agency...When i request them to investigate they said they will talk to their bank....Should i wait for them to start investigation?

Comment: Are you sure they were sending you a paper cheque?  It's not some "direct deposit" situation where the money may have gone directly into your bank account?  You could try asking at your bank, to see if a deposit in the correct amount arrived in your account at around the right time.

Comment: Hi Steve, They send me a paper check and when i asked them for direct deposit earlier they said it tedious process and might take more time... so i am sure they send me a paper check..Also they send me screen shot of their bank that check is deposited...

Comment: @Delta - That screenshot should include the back of the check where it was endorsed (and which account it was deposited into).  Assuming that it is not your signature and not your account, you and the camp ought to alert the bank that the check was fraudulently cashed.

Comment: Hi @Justin, Summer camp agency share the screen shot of their bank account where it says the check status is cleared and merchant name is mine ... the other info it has like Check Number, Reference Number, Status , Amount and Payment Date,,

Comment: @Delta - Then there is a separate place the camp can go to see the digital copy of the cashed check which will show the endorsement.  Every place I've banked has put a link to that digital copy on the statement line showing that the check cleared.  Either way, you want to see that so that you can confirm to the camp that the signature and bank account aren't yours.

Comment: Hi Justin .. thanks for information.. too see the digital camp person haa to go to bank or its available online in their account.

Comment: Camp director saying he will go to bank branch and start the investigation..and advising me that there is nothing required from my side as of now..